# Git fetch remote pulls in new branches but new branch doesn't show up

Tags: git, github

I ran these commands, but the new branch that I fetched from Github doesn't show up when I run `git branch` after running `git fetch origin`:

```
CACSVML-13295:smartconnect amills001c$ git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 426, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (223/223), done.
remote: Total 426 (delta 269), reused 287 (delta 188)
Receiving objects: 100% (426/426), 113.77 KiB | 76.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (269/269), done.
From github.csv.comcast.com:Baymax/smartconnect
 * [new branch]      enrichmentasync-module -> origin/enrichmentasync-module
 * [new branch]      github_master_now -> origin/github_master_now
 * [new branch]      master_next_localMermoryCache -> origin/master_next_localMermoryCache
 * [new tag]         0.0.4      -> 0.0.4
 * [new tag]         0.0.5      -> 0.0.5
CACSVML-13295:smartconnect amills001c$ git branch
  github_master_now
  master
* master_next
  master_with_quick_fix_for_prod
  mocha_deep_test
  priya_testing_branch
```

Is there any good reason why the new branch that was clearly fetched from the remote (origin) doesn't show up when I run the `git branch` command?

Comment: `git branch -r`—are you including the `-r`?

Comment: As mentioned above, `git branch -r` shows the remote branches, but that is remote branches *only*. You can use `git branch -a` to list all branches, both local and remote.

Answer (score 1):

It will have brought down the branch as a remote tracking branch

```
origin/<branchname>
```

you can view it with

```
git branch -r
```

If you want to work in it, you should create a local branch of the same name from it.

```
git checkout -b <branchname> origin/<branchname>
```

(In some versions of Git you may be able to just `git checkout <branchname>` and git will figure out that you want to create the new local branch from the remote tracking branch)